# Which ships can capture cities?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I was surprised when after ordering my Privateer to attack a weakened city, he conquered it for me!  I was not aware that ships can capture cities in Civ 5.

This makes me wonder: what ships are capable of capturing cities?

Comment: This is not true in the base game. Just to clarify - you're playing with Gods and Kings or Brave New World, yes?

Comment: I am playing Gods and Kings; fixed the tags.  I was just trying to steal some money from the city, and BAM!  it's mine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any ship with a melee attack can capture a city; ships with ranged attacks can't. There's even an achievement for it in the Fall Of Rome scenario.